# Ubuntu Server randomly gets DHCP address instead of keeping static IP

Tags: server, dhcp

I have a home server set up as my internet gateway. IP fowarding and such is working fine, but for some reason the server keeps grabbing a DHCP address instead of sticking with the static address I have set up in `/etc/network/interfaces`. `eth1` keeps switching over to a DHCP address (sort of oddly.. assigned by the DHCP server running on itself).

My first thought was Network Manager, but it doesn't seem to be installed.

Here's my `interfaces` file:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# External interface to the outside world
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules

# Our local network, we're the DHCP server
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address   192.168.1.1
    netmask   255.255.255.0
    network   192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

Are there any other utilities installed by default that might be resetting the network interface?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out this was a simple not having rebooted problem.

I had changed my `/etc/network/interfaces` to set the static interface, but never rebooted. This left `dhclient` running for `eth1`, which eventually went to renew the DHCP address. Killing `dhclient` fixed the problem, and with the `interfaces` file defining a static IP, it was not started on the next reboot.